# Internal sandbox error in a document-based app

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, appkit, appstore-sandbox

I have a sandboxed document-based (`NSDocument`) app. When saving files, I get weird sandboxing errors:

```
[scoped] handle 0: sandbox_extension_release error [22: Invalid argument]
[scoped] <0x600001278f00 file:///Users/username/Testi%203.exampletext>: internal sandbox error for <StopAccessing>
```

I'm also fetching file attributes for recent files using `recentDocumentURLs` in document controller, and display them in `NSOutlineView`. When I've accessed enough files, I start getting a new sandbox error, `sandbox_extension_consume returned 12`, and after that sandbox sometimes blocks the app from accessing any files.

This even happens when creating a minimal document-based app from the Xcode template. Things get saved correctly, and I can access the files I want, but errors start stacking up.

Here is a sample project which reproduces the behavior:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/9v0v65jbqkjb7ra/Sandboxed%20Doc%20App.zip?dl=1

Create a new document (window only shows the basic template, to keep it minimal) and save it. Sandbox error is immediately logged.

Document subclass in the sample is as bare bones as possible:

```objectivec
- (NSData *)dataOfType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError {
    return [_string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}

- (BOOL)readFromData:(NSData *)data ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError {
    _string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    return YES;
}
```

AFAIK, `NSDocumentController` should support sandboxing without any subclassing. Also, trying to manually stop accessing scoped bookmark of the document URL (after saving or on document close) produces an error.

Similar sandbox bug is [referred to on Twitter](https://twitter.com/ctietze/status/1422626077571227651), but I'm hardly accessing couple of files, and not over 4000.

What am I doing wrong, or is this a macOS Big Sur bug? And if not, how can it be present even in the document-based app template?

Comment: What is the swift tag for?

Comment: Whoops, a mistake. I intended to post the code in Swift at first.

Comment: What are the return value of `getResourceValue:forKey:error:` and the value of `error`? How may times is `objectValueForTableColumn` called before you get errors?

Comment: I think the problem is not `objectValueForTableColumn` but the number of files being accessed. The errors start piling up when accessing a new file that was not originally in the recent files list. It seems to be somewhat random, as I can't reproduce the issue right now — except the `<StopAccessing>` error, which happens every time when saving a file. Error value was on the lines of access denied, but I'll have to try and reproduce this to get exact value.

Comment: And weirdly enough, wrapping everything in `checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:` doesn't solve the issue, as it returns true.

Comment: The question is about two issues, are they reproducable if you remove the other issue? Is one issue caused by the other issue? How about accessing the files less often?

Comment: The core issue seems to be the `<StopAccessing>` error. If I'm not saving any files, the other problem doesn't seem to occur, at least not that often. Removing `getResourceValue:...` calls doesn't have an effect, I still get the internal sandbox error. This can be reproduced by removing `dataSource` from `NSOutlineView` in  the sample project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was that my app was requesting the list of recent files from `NSDocumentController`, and checking the edited dated by once again requesting that same list.

There seems to be a limit for how many files the app can rapidly access outside its sandbox, even if it has the permission to do so, and sandbox quickly runs out of extensions.

To fix the issue, check your code for anything that runs through a list of files and accesses them.